# Ubuntu 13.04 dimming screen flickering

Tags: nvidia, graphics, suspend

When Ubuntu goes to sleep, the screen dims slowly before turning off. As it is doing this, about every second, the screen flashes back to maximum brightness before returning to dimming. My graphics card is an NVIDIA 7900GS and I am using the NVIDIA-304 driver.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've got the same issue on my ThinkPad X230 with Ubuntu 13.10. Not sure if this issue is related to graphics card driver.

Comment: @Amja We'll probably close this. If you're still looking for an answer and the problem applies to current versions of Ubuntu, please [edit] the question to explain.